# Speaking for a company in first person

Tags: discussion

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352157/5459839) posted by a Microsoft consultant. It uses "we" and "our" as referring to the company:

> Even if we got ES6 Promises working in our desktop client it doesn't matter [...]

This reads somewhat like you would expect it on one of the company's own forums.
I was hesitating on whether this should be edited in a way to remove those first person references, obviously without changing the meaning of the answer and without hiding that the author is representing the company.

But then I notice that there are in fact many contributions using that style.

What is the right policy in this respect? Are answers using that style just fine, or should they better be phrased differently?

NB: In the mean time the author has made the update I was considering. Still, the general question remains.

Comment: I don't have a very strong opinion, but I would reckon that if the "we" isn't clear then a "Disclaimer, I work for *Company* and the "we" refers to the *Company* development team" might be sufficient in some of those cases.

Comment: Stack Overflow's user base is smart enough to recognise a royal we. There is no real improvement in editing it out.

Comment: FYI, I see that the author has in the mean time made an update himself in line of what I was thinking to do.

Comment: @Gimby, I get your point, although I don't have high expectations on how smart people are. Like George Carlin said, *'Think of how stupid the average person is, and realize half of them are stupider than that.'* ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable for companies to come to Stack Overflow to answer questions from programmers using their stuff and, where relevant, indicate that an answer comes from an authoritative perspective of an employee of that organization. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that. In fact, if you're going to [send folks to Stack Overflow to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), we encourage this kind of voice.

As long as the answers directly address the question and aren't an unsolicited poke by a third party, there's no problem. It can get a little strange if you *used* to work somewhere and now your personal account has a bunch of odd-looking "we" statements, but we can help folks sort that out with disassociation if it comes to it. The genuineness of companies coming here to answer questions instead of making people use antiquated forum software is all that matters in the end :)

Comment: Very clear, Tim! Thanks! Interesting addition on the job-change scenario. I bet that could represent a lot of rework when it comes to it.

Comment: How can we tell that they actually work at Microsoft though. That's the problem - they can't post authoritative answers by simply stating some association in their profile (we have around 20 users called Bill Gates). So they would need to point at official sources in their answers just like anyone else.

Comment: @Lundin I always knew cloning was going to be a thing!

Comment: @Lundin while at it, [you could go and ask Mark Adler to add those needed primary sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/918959) ;-) for all we know he too might be an imposter. And how about [Alan Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48710/alan-kay), unregistered!

Answer (score 9):

> Are answers using that style just fine

Yes.

> I was hesitating on whether this should be edited in a way to remove those first person references, obviously without changing the meaning of the answer and without hiding that the author is representing the company.

Mark Amery would not recommend this approach. Mark Amery thinks that it would be pointless, and that having posts write about their own authors in the third person is confusing.

Comment: I completely agree with the last paragraph -- I like the humor :) But this was honestly not what the question was about: it's not about using the first person pronoun per se, but about it referring to a company (not the author) that is not mentioned in the post.

Comment: @trincot Aha - I see your motivation now. I hadn't picked up from your original post that the problem you were trying to solve was that it was unclear to whom "we" referred. In that case, perhaps editing in a parenthetical aside solves the issue? Something like *"Even if we (the Microsoft Teams team) got ES6 Promises working ..."*? That solves the problem you're trying to solve without risking the unnatural-sounding use of the third person I poke fun at here.

Comment: Unless you're Jaqen H'Ghar, in which care it is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Mark Amery would not recommend that approach. It is known.